# Op-amp gain too big, can't figure out why

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

We are using a 741 opamp using an inverting input.
My students built a circuit, and the gain was way too high.  They had taken it apart.  So I had them build it in front of me.  The gain is still too high, and we're not sure what's going on.

As a sanity check, I had my students build a voltage divider.  An AA battery, with a voltage divider 1 MΩ and 220 Ω.   It should be approximately 0.2 mV across the 220.

We take that and connect it to the opamp circuit of the 741, +Vin to ground.
On the Op amp circuit, we have 1 MΩ feedback from output to where the signal comes in, and a 2.2 kΩ going to -Vin.

Since the input impedance of the Op Amp circuit with our two resistors is on the order of the voltage divider, we expected it to mess with the voltage.  But we measured 0.3 mV or so.

Yet the output is -10.37 V, nothing like 1M/2.2k.

Any clue what's going wrong?  Would a schematic help?  A picture of the breadboard with the wires as is?

Comment: Please add a schematic - it eliminates the ambiguity in your question. The more you post, the better.

Comment: Your hand waving description of the circuit is confusing, and also relies on your interpretation of things.  Show the schematic of how you actually hooked things up.  You do have negative feedback around the opamp, right?  Saying things like "using the inverting input" puts everything else you say in question.

Comment: 16 hours and question still not fixed, time to close this mess.

Comment: "We are using a 741 opamp" -- yuck!

Comment: Olin: 16 hours is *not* long enough. Many people do not visit this site multiple times a day. If you said 3 days and question still not fixed, and there was evidence that the OP had logged in a few times but not made any effort to clarify, I'd understand. We need to give less frequent visitors a break, though.

Comment: @Dov: When learning op-amp circuits, I would strongly suggest a feedback gain in the range of 5-50 rather than 500. You have to be careful in high-gain (100x or more, in my opinion) circuits dealing with saturation and noise issues.

Comment: @Jason: If you're coming here asking for help, I think you have a obligation to check back at reasonable intervals, especially in the beginning. This question could have been quite legitimately closed right away. We gave him a chance to fix it for a while. He refused, so now it should definitely be closed.  He's just jerking us around at this point.

Comment: What power are you giving to the 741?

Comment: @Olin: We definitely disagree, then. "He refused, so now it should definitely be closed. He's just jerking us around at this point." You ascribe far too much maliciousness to the OP.

Comment: ...and I agree that a "reasonable interval" is expected but am sure that we disagree what a "reasonable interval" is, then. I'm an active, committed user of Electronics.SE but I often have days where I am offline for at least 12 hours at a time, and often I'm away for a day or two.

Comment: @JasonS I'm more for the soft line, but if you look at the profile, he logged after the request of a schematic, and didn't provide it. So the OP is not fully justified

Comment: @clabacchio: that may be, but I still maintain we shouldn't make assumptions about the OP's time availability. Sounds like the OP is a teacher of some sort, maybe high school physics or community college or voc tech, maybe he had just a few minutes to check in quickly to see if there were any ideas. We don't know. He hasn't logged in for the last two days, and this is a holiday weekend. I'd give the guy a week from his original posting, and if we still don't hear anything then I'd vote to close.

Comment: @JasonS: what about it now?

Comment: Yep, it's time.

Comment: Indeed. Voted to close.

Comment: I apologize for letting this one go, too many things were on my plate back then...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would a schematic help?

**Yes**

This is your [circuit](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/72v4s6/inverting/) *as I read it*:

[image]

First thing, the divider by itself gives about 330 µV, because the AA battery should be 1.5 V, not 1V. And, including the input resistance of the amplifier, it shouldn't be that affected since it's 2.2k in series with the input resistance of the op-amp and the feedback resistor.

So, when connected to the amplifier, the divider gives 300µV.

Now, the amplifier's gain should be -1000/2.2 = -455, which multiplied by 300 µV gives -136 mV. If you run the simulation, you will see -56 mV: this is due to the input bias current, which for the 741 is *high* (80 nA) and unbalances the feedback divider. If you change the amplifier to the TL082 (in the simulation at least) you'll see the output going to the expected 136 mV.

Since your amplifier gives -10V, it's likely that the op-amp is saturated, and that may be caused by a missing connection somewhere: are you sure that the non inverting input is grounded? To what? **The divider, being connected to the battery, is also referenced to ground, isn't it?**

**UPDATE:** as Markrages pointed, the 741 has a maximum rated input offset voltage of 5 mV, which is one order of magnitude bigger than the signal you are amplifying. You can solve this with another op-amp (741 is one of the worst) or try to work on it with the offset nulling circuit, as suggested on the datasheet.

### EDIT:

I was thinking again about the choice of the 741: there's only one reason to use it for didactic purposes (the only use that makes sense). And it's to show the non-idealities of op-amps, as it has every flaw that you can expect from one. I've also been taught about its flaws, like slew rate, saturation range, bias current, offset and low gain.

If you want just to demonstrate how op-amps work, use a better one. And make simpler circuits (small gain and good input signal, maybe a waveform generator), to remain on the sweet spot where everything works.

Comment: lm741 has 5mV max offset voltage.  Using it to amplify a 300µV signal is not likely to work well.

Comment: @markrages true. But looking at the datasheet, there is the possibility to use an offset nulling pot

Comment: @stevenvh rearranging your math, given a 10V output it's sufficient 10/200'000 = 50+ µV offset to saturate it

Comment: Joking aside, it will give you an output offset voltage, but in your schematic even that 5mV wouldn't saturate it. I have no explanation for it either. The 1000V would be an explanation if the feedback connection is broken for some reason.

Comment: @stevenvh I think the offset explanation can work, together with bias current: consider that the feedback resistor is 1M, 10µA is enough to saturate it. A pot in the feedback could help in finding the issue

Comment: "And make simpler circuits". Well, it *was* a simple circuit: an inverting amplifier. Just two resistors, you can't go much simpler.

Comment: @stevenvh sorry, simple was referred to the amount of gain and the fact that he's amplifying from a divider, which makes things trickier

Comment: The divider came only afterwards, after the inverting amplifier didn't seem to work. But a gain of 450 is not a good idea.

Comment: I cant click your circuit to look at simulator!

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the diagram in one of the previous answers:

You need to introduce a buffering amplifier to isolate the two circuits. The bufffer would separate the voltage divider from the OpAmp.  The output resistance of the voltage divider is affecting the input resistance to the opamp.

Recalculate Vin/Vout for the COMPLETE circuit (Shown above( and you'll see that the voltage gain is not what you anticipate it to be.

Edit:

$$
\frac{V_{out}}{R_4} = \frac{V_x}{R_3}
$$

$$
\frac{R_3V_{out}}{R_4} = V_x
$$

Eq2:
$$
 \frac{V_{in}-V_x}{R_1} =\frac{V_x}{R_2} + \frac{V_x}{R_3}
$$

$$
\frac{V_{in}}{R_1} = V_x( \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2} +\frac{1}{R_3})
$$

$$
V_x = \frac{Vin}{ 1+\frac{R_1}{R_2} +\frac{R_1}{R_3}}
$$

$$
\frac{R_3V_{out}}{R_4}= \frac{Vin}{ 1+\frac{R_1}{R_2} +\frac{R_1}{R_3}}
$$

$$
V_{out}= \frac{R_4 Vin}{R_3 ( 1+\frac{R_1}{R_2} +\frac{R_1}{R_3})}
$$

Not a simply voltage divider any more now is it?

Plugging in all the values you end up with 136mV on the output.

you said you measured 300mV. Chuck your op amp. Its bad.

Answer (score -1):

The circuit as described has the 1M feedback resistor connected to the voltage divider, and the 2k2 is in series with the 1M to the inverting input.

This would produce the output described.

Return the 1M feedback resistor from output to BETWEEN the 2k2 resistor and the inverting input and your problem will be solved.